# input output C++ reading from a .txt file

Tags: c++, input, output

how can I print this to an output file and calculate sum and average of these peoples salaries by week and by overall weeks for 4 weeks...

example txt file..

```
doe       jane
williams  tom
lons      adams

 45.7   56.3   345.6  344.7  // week 1
 43.6   89.0   543.6  12.5   // week 1  person 2
 90.5   78.0  345.4  345.6  //week 1 person 3
 67.5   34.5   56.6   34.5   // week2 person 1
  etc....for 4 weeks..
```

I know there is an easier way by using loops can I get some help thanks :)

this is what I have so far

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream infile;
 ofstream outfile;

double s1, s2, s3 , s4 ,s5;
double t1, t2,t3,t4,t5;
double w1, w2,w3,w4,w5;
string personlast,personfirst,personlast2,personfirst2,personlast3,personfirst3;
double sum, average;
int numberpeople, numberofweeks;

infile.open("data.txt");
outfile.open("output.txt");

outfile<< fixed<< showpoint;
outfile<< setprecision(2);

infile>> numberpeople >> personlast >> personfirst >> personlast2 >> personfirst2>>
  personlast3 >> personfirst3 >> numberofweeks;
outfile<< " The number of salespeople are " << numberpeople <<"they are" <<
personlast << personfirst << "and " <<
 personlast2 << personfirst2 <<
 "and " << personlast3 << personfirst3 <<"Number of weeks = " << numberofweeks;


infile>> s1 >> s2 >> s3 >> s4 >> s5;
outfile <<" sales for week 1  "<< " for" << personlast << personfirst << s1 << s2
<< s3 << s4 << s5 << endl;
sum= s1+s2+s3+s4+s5;
 outfile <<"Sum of first week is " << sum<<endl;

infile >> t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4 >> t5;
outfile <<" sales for week 1  "<< " for" << personlast2 << personfirst2 << t1 << t2 
<< t3 << t4 << t5 <<endl;



infile.close();
outfile.close();
return 0;
```

Comment: It might help to state what each number within a row represents.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector`-s? With `for` loops?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch 20 rep says it's for c++ class and you can't use `std::vector`

Comment: I am very big noob so I do not understand what is std vector is or how it works..

Comment: I  need some tutoring willing to pay $20 for an hours worth of C++ help via email...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch..would you be willing to tutor via email.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework for you cause I don't want to but I'll give you something to get started with. The basic concept is to loop over the file, reading each line. Use a control like (pseudo code);

```
 while (string = readline() != EOF)
 {
     //split string on delimiters in this case spaces
     if (string piece is not an int)
     {
         // this is a name
         // set first and last name here
     }

     if (string piece is an int)
     {
        // set ints,
     }
 }
```

You'll also want some structures (these should probably be classes if you've learned about those yet) to hold your data. If you can use strings use them instead of those `char*` if you use the `char*` you'll have to declare a char array dynamically. That, or you could make them `char[64] first_name;` if that's allowed.

```
struct person {
   char *first_name;
   char *last_name;
   numbers[4] numbers;
};

struct numbers {
   float item1;
   float item2;
   float item3;
   float item4;
};
```

When you read the data you'll need to read it into instances of the person structure.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal....would you consider tutoring me tonight via email.. i would be willing to pay you $20 for an hour for your time..

Comment: thanks for the bit of code :) but..I need further explanation on what you mean..Like I mentioned would really appreciate some tutoring if you are available tonight.

Comment: @user1766270 Start by writing some code to read the file line by line using a loop. If you make some progress and edit your post I'll provide further help. Take a look at this to get a start http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/